# Python script search a text file for a word

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python script. I need to search a text file for a word that end by " s , es or ies " and the word must be greater than three letters , need to konw number of words and the word it-self .....it's hard task i cant work with it, please help me

Comment: *it's hard task i cant work with it* - then go back and learn the basics and **actually learn**? Asking us to do it for you won't help you learn anything.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example? Try iterating over the lines of the file and use `if` statements to return what you're looking for.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The Python community is fantastically helpful and supportive, but you have to show us you are at least _trying_.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comment that you need to go work on the basics.  Here are some ideas to get you started.

1) You say "search a file." Open a file and read line by line like this:

```
with open ('myFile.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
       # do something to each line
```

2) You probably want to store each line in a data structure, like a list:

```
# before you open the file...
lines = []

# while handling the file:
lines.append(line)
```

3) You'll need to work with each word.  look into the 'split' function of lists.

4) You'll need to look at individual letters of each word. Look into 'string slicing.'

All said and done, you can probably do this with 10 - 15 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to divide the task into different tasks if it feels overwhelming. 
The following code is by no means good, but hopefully it is clear enough so you can get the point.

1 First you need to get your text. If your text is in a file in your computer you need to put it into something that python can use.

```
# this code takes the content of "text.txt" and store it into my_text
with open("text.txt") as file:
    my_text = file.read()
```

2 Now you need to work with every individual word. All your words are together in a string called my_text, and you would like them separated (split) into a list so you can work with them individually. Usually words are separated by spaces, so that's what you use to separate them:

```
# take the text and split it into words
my_words = my_text.split(" ")
```

3 I don't know exactly what you want, but let's suppose you want to store separately the words in different lists. Then you will need those lists:

```
# three list to store the words:
words_s = []
words_es = []
words_ies = []
```

4 Now you need to iterate through the words and do stuff with them. For that the easiest thing to do is to use a for loop:

```
#iterate through each word
for word in my_words:

    # you're not interested in short words:
    if len(word) <= 3:
        continue  # this means: do nothing with this word


    # now, if the word's length is greater than 3, you classify it:

    if word.endswith("ies"):
        words_ies.append(word)   # add it to the list

    if word.endswith("es"):
        words_es.append(word)    # add it to the list

    if word.endswith("s"):
        words_s.append(word)     # add it to the list
```

4 Finally, outside the for loop, you can print the list of words and also get the length of the list:

```
print(words_s)     
print(len(words_s))
```

Something that you need to consider is if you want the words repeated or not. Note that the condition 'word that end by "s", "es" or "ies"' is equivalent to 'word that end by "s"'. The code above will get the words distributed in different lists redundantly. If a word ends with "ies" it also ends with "es" and "s", so it'll be stored in the three lists. If you want to avoid overlapping, you can substitute the if statements by else if statements.

Keep learning the basics as other answers suggest and soon you'll be able to understand scary code like this :D

```
with open("text.txt") as myfile:
    words = [word for word in myfile.read().split(" ") if word.endswith("s") and len(word) > 3]
    print("There are {} words ending with 's' and longer than 3".format(len(words)))
```