# Python script search a text file for specific letter in location

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python script for a challenge that will locate the amount of times the letter 'e' appears as the third letter in a word. For example, the word "they". I was wondering if anyone had any tips or had a solution to what I'm trying to solve as I am not as experienced as most.

I found this code from "[Python Script Search a Text File For A Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443605/python-script-search-a-text-file-for-a-word)" that I was trying to use as a start, if anyone has ideas of what I could alter to meet the needs listed above, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
with open("/Users/djdees/Downloads/text.txt") as myfile:
    words = [word for word in myfile.read().split(" ") if word.endswith("e") and len(word) > 3]
    print("There are {} words ending with 'e' and longer than 3".format(len(words)))
```

Thanks For Everyones Help,
DJ

Answer (score 0):

You can try `find` to search index of letter in string as the code

```
with open("/Users/djdees/Downloads/text.txt") as myfile:
    words = [word for word in myfile.read().split(" ") if word.find("e") == 2]
    print("There are {} words  with  the letter 'e' appears as the third letter".format(len(words)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we are checking if 'e' is the third letter of each word, we must check the 2nd index for every word in our file.

```
f = open("<Enter Your File's Name Here>", "r")
words = []
for line in f:
    l = line.split(" ")
    for word in l:
        if len(word) > 3 and word[2] == 'e':
            words.append(word)
print(words)
print("There are {} words ending with 'e' and longer than 3".format(len(words)))
```